# Is waking up sore a reliable indication of overtraining?

Tags: overtraining

My workout regimen is about 4 days a week lifting, split into two groups of exercise two days each, and about 2 days cardio (some running, some stationary bike). I am also on TRT, 48 years old male.

Lately, despite being in fantastic shape and probably the lowest BF in my life (thanks TRT), I have been waking up sore. The soreness goes away about 2-3 hrs into my day. Is this a reliable indicator that I am overtraining? Should I stop until I start waking up not sore?